# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. in Django 3.1

Tags: python, django, python-multiprocessing, multi-tenant

I have used Django Multitenant. I need to create a tenant creation flow in the background. so I have used multiprocessing Django.

Here my code is

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_tenant_background, args=[username,email,password,tenant_name,user.id])

p1.start()
```

and my background function is

```
def create_tenant_background(username,email,password,tenant_name,user_id):
          # my code
```

After I run the code below error in the terminal pls help me to solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: I have used windows os

Comment: try running `python manage.py migrate` and make sure you added `Multitenant` to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: All codes are correct. Ubuntu is working correctly. but not working in windows.